# Java jar for file conversion

Tags: java, jar, cmd, tabula

Using tabula jar i am converting pdf to csv file in command prompt using below code.

```
java -jar tabula-extractor-0.7.4-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar a.pdf -o a.csv
```

I am able to convert only first page of pdf to csv. but i need to convert all pages of pdf to csv. through witch  cmd i can achieve this. kindly help me.
Thnks in advance

Comment: i haven't used it .but according to the document there is a option `-p,--pages <PAGES>`   *Comma separated list of ranges, or all.
                            Examples: --pages 1-3,5-7, --pages 3 or
                            --pages all. Default is --pages 1*   .so default is page 1 that's why you get only one page

Comment: Read the [readme](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java) on their site.

Comment: I tried to add -a at the end of the above code. but i got Missing argument for a.   where can i add the option.?

Comment: @User9999 not a it's `-p`

Comment: Thnks. I solved the Issue.